# ShellExecuteEx() child always appears on top of Parent

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

This is a question concerning Windows 10 MFC/VC++ visual apps.

I have a running MFC application (Visualapp1) that I ShellExecuteEx() a second MFC application (VisualApp2) from.  Both apps will continue processing concurrently.

How do I ensure Visualapp2 always displays on top of Visualapp1.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: That's usually implemented using owner/owned relationships (see [Owned Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows)). Which would be the perfect fit, if all participating windows were owned by the same thread. Since that is not the case, you'd have to go to lengths to make sure this works (see [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)).

Comment: It's **way** easier to just have the entire GUI on a single thread, and instead let VisualApp2's UI spawn a non-GUI process that it communicates with.

Comment: Can't you detect when app 1 is being "show" again and then in that handler, post a message to app 2 to bring it to the foreground?. I have a concept in my app where a secondary run of my app halts and re-displays the first process.  So if your apps have their own "mutex" values you can easily locate your app and bring it to the fore. I think ...

Answer (score 1):

`ShellExecuteEx` doesn't create parent-child relationship between the processes, so your second app is independent.

If you use `CreateProcess`, that second app will be a child proces of your first app, giving it a priveleges to use `SetForegroundWindow()` for the child. Then you would "simply" determine WHEN you want to bring the child on top, and just do it.